# Python Syntax Error: expected an intended block

Tags: python, syntax-error

## So first i clicked on Run Module

[image: So first i clicked on Run Module]

## Then this came up

[image: Error Image 2]

**My code**

```
import time
    print("First we need to know you.")

print("Enter your name please.")
time.sleep(2)
name = input("Name: ")
print("Welcome, " + name + "!")
time.sleep(3)
criminal = input("Are you a criminal?: ")
if criminal=='Y':
```

**Right here it highlights print as red**

```
 print('Oh no')
    elif criminal=='N':
    print('Thank god!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to indent after an `if` and the `elif`:

```
if criminal=='Y':
    print('Oh no')
elif criminal=='N':
    print('Thank god!')
```

Also, don't indent after the `import`:

```
import time
print("First we need to know you.")
```

Comment: I'm very new to Python can you tell me what Indent means? (Sorry about this)

Comment: No problem :)  Just four spaces in from the start of the line.  If you look at my amended code, you can see the spaces there.  It's the way Python tells how bits of code should be put together, or put in a "block".  An "if" statement is special, because you need to know what to do for the if.  Is it just the next one line, or 4 lines?  The lines that correspond to the if should all be "indented" in order to tell Python "these lines are what to do if the statement is true".

Comment: You're welcome.  You can upvote helpful answers on the left here, and if someone solved your problem, you can click the "tick" to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to indent the `print('Oh no')`:

```
if criminal=='Y':
    print('Oh no')
elif criminal=='N':
    print('Thank god!')
```